# Mount NTFS partition with write access for everyone

Tags: 12.10, mount, ntfs, fstab

How can I mount a NTFS partition so that all user accounts on my machine have write access? My mount options are

```
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,nobootwait,uid=1000,gid=1002,fmask=113,dmask=002
```

This gives me write access but when other users try to delete a file the error message pops up

```
Cannot move file to trash, do you want to delete immediately?
```

As I understand this is because they don't have write access which is what I want to change.

I created a new group (with `gid=1002`) and assigned it as primary group to both user accounts but that didn't help. I also tried mounting without the `fmask`, `dmask` and `uid` options.

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Try ditching `fmask` and `dmask`, and add `umask=001`. This basically gives access to everyone, except execution permission to "others".

Comment: Yes, the issue still exists. I will try yout suggestion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: I found out what the issue is. To sum up: that error doesn't mean there's a "write access" issue, it just means that you can't move files to the trash, but instead you'll delete permanently. However, you should have write access normally. Try creating or deleting files. I'll post an answer in about 7 hours from now.

Comment: Well, yes, both users can create new files. But only my account (uid=1000) can move files to the trash. The other user (uid=1001) can't!

Comment: Yeah, exactly. This should work: remove all `uid`, `gid`, `dmask`, `fmask` and `umask` options and just put in the option called `permissions`. You should then be able to move to trash with the other user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **As I understand this is because they don't have write access which is what I want to change.**

No, this error message does not mean that they don't have write access. If they didn't have write access, you would not be able to right click and "Move to Trash" or "Delete" a file, or use the <kbd>Del</kbd> keyboard button. But since you're getting this error, it means that the users do have access.

After two hours of search, and reproducing this error on my computer, here's what I found out.

### Explanation

Permissions (owner, group owner, file and directory permissions) are set at the time of mounting. Only the owner can move files to trash. Why? Because when you move files to trash in an NTFS partition, a folder called `.Trash-<uid>` is created in the root directory of the partition, where `<uid>` is the `uid` of the user, and the folder's owner will be the user that's trying to delete. For example, if the username is `daniels` and the `uid` is 1000, a folder called `.Trash-1000` is created, and `daniels` would be the owner.

So, if `daniels` is the owner of the partition, he'll be able to do this normally. However, if another user (let's say called `alaa`, and `uid=1001`) tries to delete something, the system tries to create a `.Trash-1001` folder, with the owner `alaa`. But, on NTFS, the permissions are set at the time of mounting (example: it was set to `daniels`), and the "owner" of any file cannot be changed, and so the system fails to create the `.Trash-1001` folder, giving you the prompt `Cannot move file to trash, do you want to delete immediately?`.

To test this, try manually creating a folder in the root directory of the partition named `.Trash-1001` (the owner will be set to the owner of the partition). You'll find that hitting <kbd>Del</kbd> on the keyboard on any file/folder will not do anything, and the option when you right click an item will change from `Move to Trash` to `Delete`. I can't explain why it changes to `Delete`, but this is just to identify that the problem is indeed in the `.Trash-1001` folder.

In my opinion, I classify this as a bug.

### Solution <sub>(soft of...)</sub>

Remove all of your `uid=`, `gid=`, `dmask=`, `fmask=`, and `umask=` options from your mount command, and add `permissions`, so I guess your line should be like this:

```
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,nobootwait,permissions
```

I've tried this on my computer, and it works; both users can move to trash when using the NTFS hard disk.

Here's a demonstration:

```
alaa@aa-lu:~$ sudo mount -o rw,permissions /dev/sdc2 /media/he
Using default user mapping
alaa@aa-lu:~$ ls /media/he -la
total 104
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8192 Sep 24 21:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Sep 24 21:18 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 15  2012 Files on my hard disk
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Jul  9 12:18 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwx------ 1 root root     0 Jan 22  2012 System Volume Information
```

Then I went and deleted something using my username `alaa`, then logged in as another user `aaa` and deleted something too. Both of them could delete, and this is how the NTFS partition looks like:

```
alaa@aa-lu:~$ ls /media/he -la
total 104
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  8192 Sep 24 21:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Sep 24 21:18 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Dec 15  2012 Files on my hard disk
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 Jul  9 12:18 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwx------ 1 root root     0 Jan 22  2012 System Volume Information
drwx------ 1 alaa alaa     0 Sep 24 21:20 .Trash-1000
drwx------ 1 aaa  aaa      0 Sep 24 21:19 .Trash-1002
```

I don't know how it manages to do that, but it just does.

I found this page: [Ownership and Permissions | Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/#options) that explains this, as well as a forum post (http://www.tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=27540) that has some useful information. However, unfortunately I haven't read them yet, so I can't explain exactly what this `permissions` option does.

I said "Solution (sort of...)" in the title of this section because now you're not controlling who is the owner of the partition, not group owner, nor the read-write permissions. But, when mounting with the `permissions` option, you can see a "Using default user mapping", so as far as I understood, there's a "user mapping" thing that can be created to be used with `permissions`, and that mapping will have the owner/permissions that we want to set. I also have not tried mounting using `permissions` along with `uid=` and all those other options (the Tuxera link I posted should explain that though), but that might also work, by controlling owner/permissions and at the same time give access to Trash.

When I read those links, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow, somehow I missed your answer... I will definitely look into this although some early testing (mounting with `permissions` but without `uid=1000`) did not work. Even user with uid 1000 was unable to move files to trash...weird. But thanks anyway, I will give it a few more tries and see if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your fstab:

```
UUID=<YourPartitionUUID>  <YourMountPoint>  ntfs-3g  defaults,uid=1000,gid=46,utf8,dmask=000,fmask=111  0  0
```

*(If you don't have **ntfs-3g** installed, you can either try installing it or try using just **ntfs**.)*

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. I also tried various combinations of `uid` and `gid`. It seems that `gid` doesn't have any effect at all. Only the user that has his `uid` set in the mount options can move files to the trash but others still receive the error message.

Comment: I know, this is a bit frustrating for non-expert users like us. dmask and fmask values above (giving rw access to all) should be okay for you. It seems the rest needs a little bit more tinkering. Perhaps you can also try **auto,users** instead of **defaults** and **gid=100** instead of **gid=46**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alaa Ali, added the `remount` and it worked fine for me

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd2` to fix the Windows Not fully Shutdown

`sudo mount -o rw,permissions,remount /dev/sdd2 /home/disk1`